# system.new.dat vs system.img

Tags: rom-flashing

Trying to find help in restoring my OnePlus One to factory state, I found quite  a number of websites that have step-by-step instructions.

I'm trying to use `fastboot` to flash [this](https://www.oneplus.com/support/softwareupgrade/details?code=1). Because that factory image (?, the page speaks about *update*) does not offer a `flash_all.bat`, I'm following the instructions (which sadly are not for that file, OnePlus does not offer any instructions here) I found which revolve around

```
fastboot flash partitionName filename.img
```

All of these have a line I assume is the most essential one:

```
fastboot flash system system.img
```

Unfortunately the ZIP offered by OnePlus has no such file. Instead, it has three files named

```
system.new.dat
system.patch.dat
system.transfer.list
```

Can I somehow use these files instead, if so, how, and if not, where can I find the correct system.img for my OnePlus One 64 GB?

Context: I bought the OnePlus One for trying out Ubuntu Touch. Now I need to re-install Android because the phone is going to my girlfriend's mom as a gift tomorrow (at least that was the plan, turns out to be alot more diffuclt than expected) :( .

[image]

Comment: The zip file that you have is recovery-flashable zip, not the fastboot-flashable one. Just use a recovery, such as TWRP, to flash that file.

Comment: I don't think TWRP is available for Ubuntu Touch, is it? There is currently nothing left of Android other than adb and fastboot access. Even the Recovery tool on the phone has been replaced by "UBPorts Recovery".

Comment: this is a windows tool which extract system.new.dat and as a side effect it converts system.new.dat into system.img just select the whole zip file do not extract the zip https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=79713771&postcount=29

Comment: you can flash twrp from fastboot at any time `fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.3.1-0-bacon.img` https://dl.twrp.me/bacon